# Sheaf of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry, affine-schemes

I'm reading Algebraic and Arithmetic Curves written by Qing Liu. I have a question about the properties of a scheme.
Let $X$ be a scheme and $x\in X$ an arbitrary point, we can find an open subset of $X$, $U$, so that ($U$, $\mathscr{O}_X|_U$) is an affine scheme.
In a proposition it was said that $Spec \mathscr{O}_X(U)\cong U$. I couldn't show why this is correct

My attempt: $U$= Spec $A$, where $U$ is covered with $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $I$ is finite. Let $U_i=D(f_i)$, $\forall i\in I: f_i\in A$. Therefore we have $\mathscr{O}_X|_U(U_i)=A_{f_i}$. Sections of $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$ are isomorphic with $S=\{(s_i)_{i\in I}\}$ where in each tuple, $s_i$ is a section that belongs to $\mathscr{O}_X|_U(U_i)$ and $s_i$ and $s_j$ agree on their intersection. I tried to define an isomorphism from Spec $S$ to $U$

I would be thankful for any help

One additional question, if $s_i$ and $s_j$ belong to $A_{f_i}$ and $A_{f_j}$ respectively where they agree on the intersection, does this mean we can represent them as $\dfrac{a_i}{f_i^m}$ and $\dfrac{a_j}{f_j^n}$ so that $\exists t\in\mathbb{N}: (f_if_j)^t(a_if_j^n-a_jf_i^m)=0$ ?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $\operatorname{Spec}\mathscr O_X(U) \cong U$? Otherwise, what you have written is an isomorphism between a ring and a topological space, which I'm not sure how to interpret.

Comment: Basically, if $U\cong\text{Spec}A$, then $\mathscr{O}_X(U)\cong \mathscr{O}_U(U)\cong A$, we take $\text{Spec}$ and get $Spec \mathscr{O}_X(U)\cong \text{Spec}A\cong U$. Note that these isomorphisms should fit into some commutative diagram.

Comment: @YangPei Thanks, sorry if it's a trivial question, why is this part $\mathscr{O}_U(U)\cong A$ correct

Comment: @NafiseModaresi. $\mathscr{O}_U(U)$ is $\mathscr{O}_{\text{Spec}A}(\text{Spec}A)$, and for an affine scheme $\text{Spec}A$, the global section of structure sheaf is just $A$.